# Directive specific styles in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have some directives in my application which are loaded only in certain components. Currently all the styles related to these directives are globally defined in style.css.

Instead of adding these styles globally, is there a way I can hook separate style URLs for directive just like how we do in components.

e.g

```
@Directive ({
    selector: '[foobar]',
    styleUrls: [
       'foobar.directive.css'
    ]
})
```

Comment: I found an alternative here:
[Angular2 Styles in a Directive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35915497/3918612)

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to add styles to directives, only to components.

See also

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Directive-decorator.html
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Component-decorator.html